# WIX property from a Custom Action into a WIX variable

Tags: variables, wix, custom-action

May seem like a trivial question but I cant get it to work.

QUESTION: Can u set a WIX property from a Custom Action into a WIX variable?

This is what I have tried:

```
<?define VAR = "ProductName"?>

<Product Id="*" Name="$(var.VAR)" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">

<Property Id="VAR">ProductName</Property>

<CustomAction Id='GetProductName' BinaryKey='GetProductName' DllEntry='GetProductName' Execute='immediate' Return='check' />
<CustomAction Id="CustomAction1" Return="check" Execute="immediate" Property="VAR" Value="[PRODUCTNAME]" />


<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action='GetProductName' After='AppSearch' />
  <Custom Action='CustomAction1' After='GetProductName' />
</InstallUISequence>
```

PRODUCTNAME is the property i have set from my custom action.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WiX variables are a build / compile concept, not a installtime concept. It isn't possible.

What are you really trying to do?  If you are trying to change the ProductName property during the installation, be aware that you can't.  That property is immutable once the installation starts.

Comment: Is there any way of getting around this, this is one of the requirements that I have to meet. If not WIX will have to be scrapped..:(

Comment: I've developed a work around, If i recreate the dialogs then I can set their title to be a property..:) Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, you can use any formatted expression in the dialog titles. It's just ProductName itself that is immutable.

Comment: Accepted your answer as it is to the point and helped my understand variables abit more. Thanks