# Why I don't have access to $(var.Configuration) in Product.wxs?

Tags: .net, wix

I want to specify the dll path according to the project configuration. I added my project to Installer references.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you searched for the error (Undefined preprocessor variable) instead, you would have found a lot of answers on that topic, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/47594208/1331719

For your particular case edit the DefineConstants and add `Configuration=$(Configuration)` in all your configurations.

```
<DefineConstants>Configuration=$(Configuration)</DefineConstants>
```

UPDATE:

If you are not building against a wixproj then set the variable in the candle.exe command line with `-d<Name>[=<value>]`

`candle.exe -dConfiguration=Release`

Comment: I've added the candle.exe command line, if it doesn't work the perhaps you can share more of your project, especially your setup.build

Answer (score 0):

The WiX MSBuild targets provide that. If you're not using the WiX MSBuild targets, you have to provide it yourself.

Comment: could you give me an example please?